# Use of unassigned out parameter

Tags: c#, .net, oop, url

I'm passing list of data to parse further

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    var urls = new List<MyUrl>();
    ...
    ExtractData(out urls);
}

private static void ExtractData(out urls)
{

   ...
   foreach(var item in items)
   {
       urls.Add(new MyUrl{ Url = item.Url });
   }       
}
```

I'm getting vs error

> Use of unassigned out parameter 'urls'

Why I'm getting this error since I'm assigning new object into existing list?

Comment: out parameter is supposed to be set in the ExtractData method. `out` parameters cannot be used to pass input from caller but it's strictly for getting output from called method.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the name of the method here `private static void(out urls)`

Comment: You should not be passing this as `out` in the first place. Pass the *reference*, not *a reference to a variable containing a reference*. You pass with `out` when you intend to change *the variable*, but you don't intend to change the variable, you intend to change *the object that is referred to by the value of the variable*, so *pass the value*, not *a reference to the variable*. Simply remove the `out` and you'll be fine.

Comment: I strongly agree with Eric. Also, from my experience, I always advice to avoid using `out` unless absolutely necessary. There's always a better approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out variable should be defined under called method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx

> Although variables passed as out arguments do not have to be
>   initialized before being passed, the called method is required to
>   assign a value before the method returns.

Thus you should write as:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    List<MyUrl> urls = null;
    ...
    ExtractData(out urls);
}
private static void(out List<MyUrl> urls)
{
  urls = new List<MyUrl>();
   ...
   foreach(var item in items)
   {
       urls.Add(new MyUrl{ Url = item.Url });
   }       
}
```

Comment: This moves the responsibility for creating the List, and it would be much simpler as a function with `return`.

Comment: I think you're missing a method name there on the second one, mate